# shared resources like bandwidth synchronization

Tags: c++, synchronization

I am reading abouting thread synchronization in Applied C++

> Shared resources can also be less tangible things like bandwidth, the
>   amount of information your application can send or receive per unit of
>   time. For example, many threads can simultaneously request information
>   from sockets, such as fetching web pages or other information. Most
>   operating systems can manage hundreds or thousands of simultaneous
>   connections and will patiently wait for information to arrive. The
>   management is not the problem, but the timely receipt of information
>   is. If the machine running your application needs a constant stream of
>   information, you may find that you are trying to access more
>   information than you have available bandwidth to receive.

My questions on above paragraph are

1. What does author mean by "The management is not the problem, but the timely receipt of information is. " Request to elobarate with simple example.
2. Another question is What does author mean by "If the machine running your application needs a constant stream of information, you may find that you are trying to access more information than you have available bandwidth to receive." Why author talking about machine needs constant stream and we will find that we are trying to access more information then available band width. Request to elobarate with simple example.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Data will arrive -- eventually.

   They argue that if each thread requests data independent from the others, that may lead to a situation where urgently required data that one thread requested is stuck in a queue behind something another thread requested.

   If your application's correct functioning depends on data to be available at a certain point (e.g. a video streaming application), then you need explicit bandwidth management, either cooperatively (threads communicating with each other), or preemptively (configuration of an external component).
2. The best example is the video streaming application. If your video data does not arrive in time, playback stops even if there is sufficient computing power.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Can you please eloborate what is bandwidth here.

Comment: The amount of data that can be transferred to your host in a given time. E.g. if you have ADSL with 16 Mbps (~1.8 MB/s), then nine threads using 200 kB/s bring the connection to its limit, and if you add another one, all of them will get less performance.